# How to Save Pictures from MediaLibrary to IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I have the requirement to save the 5 most recent pictures from the 'Saved Pictures' album from MediaLibrary into IsolatedStorage. I am not quite sure the best way to accomplish this task. So far I am searching through the MediaLibrary for the 'Saved Pictures' album. If the album exists and pictures exist within that album, I need to take the most recent 5 images that start with the filename "TestApp" and save them to IsolatedStorage. The names will be used to update a tile, so the filepath of each image is very specific. What I have so far is as follows, I'm jus tnot sure how to save `p.GetImage()` (which returns an image from the MediaLibrary of type `System.IO.Stream`) to IsolatedStorage with the updated filename

```
private PictureCollection _pictures = null;

    public void StoreCycleTileImages()
    {
        string _photoPath = @"\Shared\ShellContent";
        string _photoFilename = null;
        int i = 0;

        using (MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
        {
            foreach (PictureAlbum album in library.RootPictureAlbum.Albums)
            {
                if (album.Name == "Saved Pictures")
                {
                    _pictures = album.Pictures;

                    if(_pictures != null)
                    {
                        //search for the most recent pictures in the album with the correct file name
                        foreach (var p in _pictures.Reverse())
                        {
                            if (i >= 5)
                                return;

                            if (p.Name.Substring(0,7) == "TestApp")
                            {
                                i += 1;

                                using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                                {
                                    if (!storage.DirectoryExists(_photoPath))
                                    {
                                        storage.CreateDirectory(_photoPath);
                                    }

                                    //Update file name
                                    _photoFilename = @"" + i.ToString();

                                    if (storage.FileExists(_photoPath + @"\" + _photoFilename))
                                    {
                                        storage.DeleteFile(_photoPath + @"\" + _photoFilename);
                                    }

                                    //use p.GetImage() stream to save to IsolatedStorage with updated file name
                                    //??
                                }
                            }
                        }                            
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run your code - you miss the file extension while creating file name (you should consider that it can be jpg, png, or other image). My working code (copying fragment) looks like this:

```
photoFilename = @"" + i.ToString() + p.Name.Substring(p.Name.LastIndexOf('.'));
if (storage.FileExists(_photoPath + @"\" + _photoFilename))
{
    storage.DeleteFile(_photoPath + @"\" + _photoFilename);
}
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = storage.CreateFile(_photoPath + @"\" + _photoFilename))
    p.GetImage().CopyTo(file);
```